# How can I get included version of npm while installing nodejs?

Tags: node.js, npm

I downloaded the latest version of `node.js`, where it is mentioned that
while installing it, there is included version of `npm 6.14.6`.

And I have installed also, hoping that the latest node js and npm would be installed.
But it went wrong, it installed with latest node js and with the old version of `npm version 4.6.1`
I have tried out many times to install latest version of npm, but getting

> `npm error cb.apply is not a function`

Comment: have you tried `npm install -g npm` ?

Comment: i have tried, caught same error, any other solution plz!!

Comment: main problem is with the info, in node.org, its clearly mentioned that after installing latest verion of LTS, there you will be installing the npm version around 5-6, but after installing the latest LTS version of node.js, while checking npm version there installed npm version 4.6.1. I don't know how it comes bro

Comment: Might be best to uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: well, i tried bro. now mine last option is to set out path, let see it works or not

Comment: thanks a lot bro, for replying the messages bro, finally worked out just removing my old installed npm file and setting path to new installed node js file location bro!! its now showing the correct version of npm.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I think npm is broken now.

Comment: bro, since npm is going through updating versions, the errors are being glanced and resolved. Yeah, you are right in some point, especially its very problematic for beginners, but trying alot makes you prefect. I tried the activity mentioned just above your comment and worked out perfectly, Ahmed, try it out and works well!!